# Shall I buy a Large size shell if I am wearing Medium size Down Jacket?

Tags: clothing, shelter, rain, snowboarding, down

So that I can have some spaces to wear Down or Fleece inside the jacket?

Normally Large size shell is too large for me, or I should buy the same size so as fit as possible?

Comment: I am voting to close this question.  It really depends on the sizing of the specific shell that you are talking about; some brands leave more room than others.  You do not want the insulation heavily compressed or it will not work correctly.  You really need to try on the combination to see how it fits.

Comment: @Ryan I find most shells fit large for this reason.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I believe this to be a good question which may be difficult to answer. What you explained here in your comment could be part of that answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer is as simple as:

1. If you own a mid-layer wear it to the store when you purchase the shell.
2. If you own a shell wear it to the store when you purchase your mid-layer.
3. If you don't own either purchase them together to ensure best fit.

There are several different [layering systems](http://www.outdoorgearlab.com/a/11070/How-to-Layer-Clothing-for-Each-Season)   find what works for you and try everything on in store.  If you would like to purchase something online and cannot find the same model to try on in store, at the very least try on some gear from that same manufacturer to get an idea of their fit.

Try contacting a manufacturers retail store close to your location and inquire about their return policy.  For example I know in Canada I am able to buy North Face from their website, have it delivered to my home address and if it does not fit I can return it to the retail location in my city no questions asked.